# What does '+' in abstract type definition mean?

Tags: ocaml

I'm seeing a declaration for what seems to be an abstract type that looks like:

```
 type +'a io
```

What does the '+' indicate there?

Answer (score 2):

It says the type has covariant subtyping with respect to the parameter type. So if `T` is a subtype of `U`, then `T io` is a subtype of `U io`.

Comment: Practically speaking, what are the implications? Why would (or should) one make the declaration with the '+' as opposed to just: type 'a io   ?

Comment: The co-/contr-variance can't be inferred, so you have to declare it. The reason to declare it in the first place is subtle, and is explained by @gasche here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15561714/when-does-the-relaxed-value-restriction-kick-in-in-ocaml/15562110#15562110