# Why this weakly polymorphic type?

Tags: polymorphism, ocaml, value-restriction

```
module type M = sig
  type ('k, 'v) t
  val foo : 'k -> ('k, 'v) t
end

module M : M = struct
  type ('k, 'v) t = ('k * 'v) list
  let foo k = []
end
```

In this little example, why would `M.foo 123` have a weakly polymorphic type, `(int, '_a) M.t)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the value restriction, I believe. `M.foo 123` is not a value, it's a function application. So it can't have fully polymorphic type.

You can actually fix this by declaring `'v` to be covariant in your module type. I never personally tried this before, but it does seem to work:

```
# module type M = sig
  type ('k, +'v) t
  val foo: 'k -> ('k, 'v) t
  end;;
module type M = sig type ('k, +'v) t val foo : 'k -> ('k, 'v) t end
# module M: M = struct
  type ('k, 'v) t = ('k * 'v) list
  let foo k = []
  end;;
module M : M
# M.foo 123;;
- : (int, 'a) M.t = <abstr>
```

I believe this works because of the ["relaxed value restriction"](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/papers/garrigue-value_restriction-fiwflp04.pdf).

I learned about this use of the variance annotation from @gasche here: [When does the relaxed value restriction kick in in OCaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15561714/when-does-the-relaxed-value-restriction-kick-in-in-ocaml/15562110#15562110)