# Why this OCaml code does not subject to the value restriction

Tags: ocaml, value-restriction

I don't understand that the function (*my_path_mapper*) doesn't subject to the value restriction.

```
# let rec my_map ~f l =
  match l with
    [] -> []
  | h::t -> f h::my_map f t;;
      val my_map : f:('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list = <fun>
# let my_path_mapper =
  my_map ["/usr/sbin"; "/usr/bin"; "/sbin"; "/bin"; "/usr/games"; "/usr/local/games"];;
  val my_path_mapper : f:(string -> 'a) -> 'a list = <fun>
```

Please teach me Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OCaml has a "relaxed value restriction." You can read about it here:

[Jacques Garrigue, Relaxing the Value Restriction](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/papers/garrigue-value_restriction-fiwflp04.pdf)

Here is a previous discussion on StackOverflow:

[When does the relaxed value restriction kick in in OCaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15561714/when-does-the-relaxed-value-restriction-kick-in-in-ocaml?s=1%7C3.9878)