# How to use Map / define a type which actually is a Map in OCaml?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I am going to practicing using `Map` in Ocaml.

I found that the usage of `Map` is quite different from `List`, `Array`, etc.

I understand it is applying `functor` which I haven't learnt yet. but it is fine.

---

Here is my `IntMap`

`module IntMap = Map.Make(struct type t = int let compare = compare end)`

So, now I can use `IntMap` to `add` by `IntMap.add x y map`, etc, right?

---

I have a few questions:

1. How do I control the type of `value` in the `map`?
2. If I want a alias type for my `IntMap`, what should I do? I can do `type 'a my_type = 'a list`, but how to do for `map`?
3. I find that `IntMap` is like `List` and both of them are actually `modules`. But `List` has a type of `list`, what about the `map`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q:

> How do I control the type of value in the map?

You don't (need to), `'a IntMap.t` is a parametrized type that contains values of type `'a`. A single module `IntMap` can therefore be used for map from ints to ints, from ints to bools, ints to functions... (of course a single map value can only contain bindings of a single type). Furthermore there is no reason to try to constrain the type of `IntMap.empty`, just as there is no reason to force `[]` to be of any type other than `'a list`.

Q:

> If I want a alias type for my IntMap, what should I do? I can do type 'a my_type = 'a list, but how to do for map?

This way:

```
type 'a imap = 'a IntMap.t
```

Q:

> I find that IntMap is like List and both of them are actually modules. But List has a type of list, what about the map?

This is `Intmap.t`.

Comment: I saw in the doc, `type +'a t The type of maps from type key to type 'a`, what is the meaning of `+` inside?

Comment: @JacksonTale see this question: [Why there is a plus sign before this type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15305499/why-there-is-a-plus-sign-before-this-type/)